# Javascript function runs only once

Tags: javascript, php

Inside a php class I am defining a table which displays a list of clients which one need to contact. In column 7 I have integrated a checkbox so when the user call the client, he/she ticks into this checkbox.

The problem is that the JS function runs the first-time and then the second time it says: default.php?page=_PhoneBankingP1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: contacted is not defined(…)

The modules in use are listed below:

```
public function phonebank($townCode,$streetCode){           
            $query  =   "SELECT clientId, clientFirstname1, clientLastname1, clientAddress, ";
            $query  .=  "       clientMailshot, clientPhone1, clientMobile1, clientContacted, min(clientDoB) ";
            $query  .=  "FROM _clients ";
            $query  .=  "WHERE  _clients.streetCode = '{$streetCode}' and ";
            $query  .=  "       _clients.townCode   = '{$townCode}' and ";
            $query  .=  "       _clients.GE = 'Y' ";
            $query  .=  "GROUP BY clientAddress ";
            $result =   $this->db->query($query);


            $output = "";
            if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ){
                $output .=  "<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information!</strong> All the residents shown below have been extracted from the last Electoral Register.</div>";
                $output .=  "<table class='table table-striped' style='font-size:10pt;' id='myTable' >";
                $output .=      "<thead>";
                $output .=          "<tr>";
                $output .=              "<th>ID #</th>";
                $output .=              "<th>Name</th>";
                $output .=              "<th>Address</th>";
                $output .=              "<th>T</th>";
                $output .=              "<th>Phone</th>";
                $output .=              "<th>Mobile</th>";
                $output .=              "<th class='text-center'>Contacted</th>";
                $output .=          "</tr>";
                $output .=      "</thead>";
                $output .=      "<tbody>";


                while ( $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $output .=  "<tr>";
                    $output .=      "<td><a href='default.php?page=_clientDetails&id=".$record['clientId']."&mode=edit' style='color: #000;'><span class='pb-clientId'>".$record['clientId']."</span></a></td>"; 
                    $output .=      "<td><span class='pb-fullname'>".$record['clientFirstname1']." ".$record['clientLastname1']."</span></td>";
                    $output .=      "<td>".$record['clientAddress']."</td>";
                    $output .=      "<td>".$record['clientMailshot']."</td>";
                    $output .=      "<td>".$record['clientPhone1']."</td>";
                    $output .=      "<td>".$record['clientMobile1']."</td>";

                    // Makes a checkbox selected
                    if ( $record['clientContacted'] == 'Y'){
                        $optContacted = ' checked ';
                    } else {
                        $optContacted = '';
                    }

                    //$output .=    "<td class='text-center' ><button id='btn-contacted-".$record['clientId']."' onclick='street.clientContacted(&quot;{$record['clientId']}&quot;,&quot;{$record['clientContacted']}&quot;)' class='btn btn-success'>Contacted</button></td>";

                    $output         .=  "<td align='center'>";
                    $output         .=      "<input type='checkbox' id='col7-".$record['clientId']."'  onclick='contacted(&quot;".$record['clientId']."&quot;);' value='1' ".$optContacted." />";
                    $output         .=  "</td>";


                    $output .=  "</tr>";
                }

                $output .=      "</tbody>";
                $output .=  "</table>";
                $output .=  "<br/>";

                echo $output;

            } else {
                echo "No Clients Found in this street";
            }
        }
```

---

Then the test JS function required to update the MYSQL is:

```
function contacted(id) {
var clientId    =   id;
var col7        =   "col7-"+clientId;
var col7value   =   $("#"+col7).is(':checked');
var data        =   id+"\n"+col7+"\n"+col7value;

alert(data);

//Read checkbox state
if (col7value =='false'){
    contacted = 'N';
} else {
    contacted = 'Y';
}   

$.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    url:        "_backend/_core/_database/update_Phonebank.php",
    data:       {
        "id":           clientId,
        "contacted":    contacted
    },
    dataType:   "text",
    success:    function(data){
    }
})  
}
```

I will appreciate if you can help me out to decide my the function is not being read the second time.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. It's hard to see what is going on in your example. Is the PHP relevent? Can't you provide a cut down version of the HTML it generates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define a function:

```
function contacted(id) {
    //...
}
```

But *within* that function, you *overwrite* the function with a value:

```
contacted = 'N';
```

So the next time you try to invoke `contacted()` you're trying to call a string as if it was a function.

Give your variables unique names:

```
var wasContacted = '';
//...
wasContacted = 'N';
// etc.
```

That way you're not overwriting things you don't want to overwrite.

Additionally, using the `var` keyword to declare your variables will define them within that specific scope (such as within that function), instead of just putting them on the `window` object.  (You *can* have variables of the same name in different scopes without affecting each other.)

Comment: @Jonasw: Optional, but I agree it's certainly recommended in this case.